# how to close the mongodb connection without generating journal files when close the node.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, journal

My node.js based app connects to a mongodb database, when I manually close the node.js app, it will trigger the function below to close the mongodb connection.

```
//  Process on exit and signals.
process.on('exit', function() { terminator(); });

['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT', 'SIGBUS',
 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGPIPE', 'SIGTERM'
].forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    process.on(element, function() { terminator(element); });
});

function terminator(sig) {
      mongoose.connection.close();    
      process.exit(1);
      console.log('%s: Node server stopped.'.red, Date(Date.now()) );
}
```

However  when I closed the node.js app, mongodb connection will be closed safely as well. But in my situation,  mongodb will create three journal files in the /var/lib/mongodb/journal :prealloc.0 prealloc.1  prealloc.2. The three journal files are too big.

Why and what is the good way to close the mongodb connection without generating these journal files when node.js app is about to close?

Comment: Are you sure the generation of the journal files is in any way related to the way you terminate the connection from your node.js application?

Comment: When the preallocation- and journaling files are too big for your use-case, you can reduce their size. But that's a configuration question you should ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: so far it is the only reason I could figure out. Because these journal files only appear after I close the node.js application.